# Parentheses in Python's functions and decorators(wrappers)

Tags: python, wrapper, nested, python-decorators

Thanks for reading my question. As I'm still new to Python, I would like to ask about the () in Python.

```
def addOne(myFunc):
    def addOneInside():
        return myFunc() + 1
    return addOneInside # <-----here is the question

@addOne
def oldFunc():
    return 3

print oldFunc()
```

Please note that on line four, although the programme returns a function, it does not need parentheses(). Why does it NOT turn out with an error for syntax error? Thank you very much for your answers in advance!

Comment: Indentation. Python uses it to determine the start and end of functions. Add one level of indentation to the code inside the `addOne` function.

Comment: Which version of python? What is the exact syntax error?

Comment: You must really show us the exact error which Python is showing to you. As I see, everything should work fine with Python 2.7, but we need to know Ptyhon version the line of the error and the message for the error. Thanks

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. However, this is no syntax error or other kinds of error in this question. I just hope to understand more the use of ()! Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: Wait, so does it give you a syntax error or not? `Why does it turn out with an error for syntax error?`

Comment: If I add () to it, it will turns out with an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are used to run a function, but without them the name still refers to the function just like a variable.

```
return myFunc() + 1
```

This will evaluate the `myFunc` function, add 1 to its value and then return that value. The brackets are needed in order to get the function to run and return a numeric value.

```
return addOneInside
```

This is not actually running `addOneInside`, it is merely returning the function as a variable. You could assign this to another name and store it for later use. You could theoretically do this:

```
plusOne = addOneInside
plusOne()
```

And it will actually call the `addOneInside` function.

The particular instance in your initial question is known as a Decorator, and it's a way for you to perform code on the parameters being passed to your function. Your example is not very practical, but I can modify it to show a simple use case.

Let's say that you want to only have positive numbers passed to your function. If `myFunc` is passed a negative number, you want it to be changed to 0. You can manage this with a decorator like this.

```
def addOne(myFunc):
    def addOneInside(num):
        if num < 0:
            num = 0
        return myFunc(num)
    return addOneInside # <-----here is the question

@addOne
def oldFunc(number):
    return number
```

To explain, the `@addOne` is the decorator syntax, and it's attaching the `addOneInside` function to be called on the argument/s of `oldFunc` whenever you call it. So now here's some sample output:

```
oldFunc(-12)
>>> 0
oldFunc(12)
>>> 12
```

So now you could add logic to `oldFunc` that operates independently of the parameter parsing logic. You could also relatively easily change what parameters are permitted. Maybe there's also a maximum cap to hit, or you want it to log or note that the value shouldn't be negative. You can also apply this decorator to multiple functions and it will perform the same on all of them.

[This blogpost](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/) explained a lot for me, so if this information is too brief to be clear, try reading the long detailed explanation there.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! But for line 1 def addOne(myFunc): Why shouldn't I make it myFunc() ?

Comment: @Steven I expanded my answer, it's a big complex topic and I'm not sure how familiar you are with Python so I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: I really am grateful to your answer! I will definitely spend time to digest your answer and read the blogpost you recommended. Thanks for your time. I am clearer about the concept now :)
I'm just wondering how did you experts learn from scratch ? any advice for me? i'm a psych major student.

Comment: @Steven Glad to help. It involves some quirky Python stuff so I hope you can follow it all!

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation in function `addOne()` was incorrect (I have fixed it), but I don't think that this was your problem.

If you are using Python3, then `print` is a function and must be called like this:

```
print(oldFunc())
```

Comment: Please don't "correct" code in the question when it's about syntax errors!

Comment: @ReyCharles : that would be a valid point if there was in fact a syntax error in that block of code, however, there wasn't. There is a potential syntax error with the `print` statement, and that has been left in tact.

Comment: Thanks for helping me fix the minor problem. It helps others read my question more clearly!